# Trying to write files on multiple lines

Tags: vb.net, file

i am trying to have variables linked to together like this: (login,pass,name) i want to have several line of those but whenever i register it clears the file help would be appreciated thanks.

```
Private Sub btn_register_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_register.Click
    Dim newline As String
    Dim anything As String

    password = txt_passwordregister.Text
    username = txt_usernameregister.Text

    If password <> "" And username <> "" Then

        If validatepass() = False Then

            MsgBox("please enter more than 8 characters")
        Else
            newline = txt_usernameregister.Text & "," & txt_passwordregister.Text

            If rad_student.Checked Then

                anything = newline & "," & txt_fullname.Text

                Student.WriteLine(anything)
                Student.Close()
            Else
            End If

            MsgBox("You are now registered!")

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The issue is presumably the way you're opening the file but, as you haven't shown that bit, we can only guess. It doesn't really make sense that you're closing a file in that code that you haven't opened there but that's not the only thing that doesn't really make sense there. Most importantly though, if you want top append to an existing file then make sure to open the file for appending rather than overwriting. Read the documentation for the types and members you're using to open the file to ensure that you actually understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to specify what kind of file you are talking to. 
but since you don't actually indicate something in particular, here i used StreamWriter to append lines of text to a file.

```
    Using studentWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("(<path>\<filename>.<txt>)", True)
        studentWriter.WriteLine(anything)
    End Using
```

sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt show what's happening with the object **Student** before..
We assume you are using StreamWriter here??
Our best guess is that you open the file in new file mode rather than append mode..

To enable Append mode, provide the parameter when you create the **Student** object like this :

```
Dim Student as New StreamWriter("[File Location]",[Append Mode])
```

When [Append Mode] is True it will append the file and write after the last line you've written into it before.

When [Append Mode] is False it will treat the file as a new file and all the content inside will be lost.